# Go json.Unmarshal does not work with type definition of json.RawMessage

Tags: go

I have a small Go program like this:

```golang
package main

import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    bs := []byte(`{"items": ["foo", "bar"]}`)

    data := Data{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type Data struct {
    Items []Raw `json:"items"`
}

// If I do this, this program panics with "illegal base64 data at input byte 0"
type Raw json.RawMessage

// This works
type Raw = json.RawMessage
```

Why does `json.Unmarshal` work with type alias but not type definition?  What does that error message mean?

Comment: This is unrelated to JSON and just how methods work with defined types and type aliases.

Comment: @Volker This is how I came across the issue.  And the error message doesn't give anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new type definition:

```
type Raw json.RawMessage
```

The `Raw` type is derived from `json.RawMessage`, but it is a new type without any of the methods defined for `json.RawMessage`. So, if `json.RawMessage` has a json unmarshaler method, `Raw` does not have that. Code such as following will not recognize a variable `t` of type `Raw` as a `json.RawMessage`:

```
if t, ok:=item.(json.RawMessage); ok {
  ...
}
```

This is a type alias:

```
type Raw = json.RawMessage
```

Here, `Raw` has all the methods `json.RawMessage` has, and type assertion to `json.RawMessage` will work, because `Raw` is simply another name for `json.RawMessage`.